# Handling mismatch of types of a data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

So, I've create this data type:

```
data Jogo = JogoInstance {
    rodada, golsMandante, golsVisitante :: Int,
    timeMandante, timeVisitante :: String
} deriving (Generic, Show)
```

This function is reponsible for getting the data from the database:

```
lerJSON :: IO [Jogo]
lerJSON = do
  input <- B.readFile "db/jogos.json"

  let jogos = decode input :: Maybe [Jogo]

  case jogos of
    Nothing -> return []
    Just jogos -> return jogos
```

And this is an example of a tuple of the database:

```
{
        "rodada": 1,
        "timeMandante": "Flamengo",
        "timeVisitante": "Palmeiras",
        "golsMandante": 5,
        "golsVisitante": 1
    }
```

So, how can handle a mismatch exception if in the field "golsMandante" I type a string?

Comment: Do you mean in the code, rather than fixing your JSON file?

Comment: Yes. I want to show a message error to the user

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eitherDecode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:eitherDecode):

> ```
> eitherDecode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Either String a
> ```
>
> Like decode but returns an error message when decoding fails.